# Why can't I display records with ngTable

Tags: html, angularjs, rest, ngtable

I was trying to display records on html using ngTable. The records are retrieved from server side through rest api.

html:

```
<div class="container">
        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="false">
            <tr ng-repeat="report in $data">
                <td title="'ReportId'" filter="{ reportid: 'text'}" sortable="'reportid'">
                    {{report.reportid}}</td>
                <td title="'SampleId'" filter="{ sampleid: 'text'}" sortable="'sampleid'">
                    {{report.sampleid}}</td>
                <td title="'MRN'" filter="{ mrn: 'text'}" sortable="'mrn'">
                    {{report.mrn}}</td>
                <td title="'Diagnosis'" filter="{ diagnosis: 'text'}" sortable="'diagnosis'">
                    {{report.diagnosis}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Controller.js

```
ristoreApp.controller("fmCtrl",
    ['$scope', 'fmFactory', 'NgTableParams', function($scope, fmFactory, NgTableParams) {
        $scope.selection = '0';
        $scope.fmSearch = function () {
            if ($scope.selection == '0') {
                $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10          // count per page
                }, {
                    getData: function (params) {
                        return fmFactory.getAll().then(function(data) {
                            params.total(data.inlineCount);
                            return data.results;
                        });
                    }
                });
                $scope.tableParams.reload();
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Factory js

```
ristoreApp.factory("fmFactory", ['$http', '$window',
    function ($http, $window) {
        var service = {};

        service.getAll = function () {
            var url = SERVER + "/ristore/foundation/";
            return $http({
                headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.getItem("access_token")},
                url: url,
                method: 'GET',
                crossOrigin: true
            })
        }

        return service;
    }]);
```

The factory definitely returns records from server correctly, because when I debug it, it shows the data of the response. 
[image: resonse]

However it does not show anything on the page. What went wrong?

Comment: Remove the filters from your table as it seems unlikely you expect 'text' to appear in the values returned

Comment: @Palamino Removed all the filters in the view and still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these things

1. Change <strike>`$scope.tableParams`</strike> in controller to `this.tableParams`
2. Change <strike>`<div ng-controller="fmCtrl">`</strike> in view  to `<div ng-controller="fmCtrl as fm">`
3. Change <strike>`ng-table="tableParams"`</strike> in view to `ng-table="fm.tableParams"`

Documentation: http://ng-table.com/#/loading/demo-external-array

**Update 1**: Change the `return rmFactory.getAll()` like this,

```
return fmFactory.getAll().then(function(response) {
    var reports = response.data;
    params.total(reports.length);
    return reports;
});
```

**Update 2**: Add this line to controller beginning (first line)

```
var self = this;
```

The first change we made, rewrite it like this.

```
self.tableParams
```

**Update 3**: We removed `$scope` and used `this` because the documentation was using that. `this` did not work here because, we were inside `$scope.fmSearch`. So to get this of the controller, we stored it in a variable `self` and accessed it. You can rename `self` to any name of your choice.

Comment: please verify `data` in the response has inlineCount`:Number and `results`:Array?

Comment: good point and no. I removed `params.total(data.inlineCount);` and changed `data.results` to `data`. Still the same. The data in response is just a list of json objects and nothing else

Comment: can you show what your response is by editing the question?

Comment: whats `console.log(reports.length)`?

Comment: did that, now I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined` for last line of controller

Comment: change it to `self.tableParams.reload();`

Comment: it works. Can you explain why the change from $scope to `this` and then to `self`?